# Switch Menu Java

Tags: java, netbeans, switch-statement

I have a switch menu and I want it to loop the entire menu including the directions but it just keeps looping the operation i select.  How do I change it?  I switched from a do/while to just a while loop.

```
 int count = 0;

    String first;
    String last;
    String num;
    Contact person;

    System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
    System.out.println("Type c to create");
    System.out.println("Tpe e to edit");
    System.out.println("Tpe d to delete");
    System.out.println("Type q to quit");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char choice = input.next().charAt(0);

    AddressBook addressBook = new AddressBook();
    while ('q' != choice) {
        switch (choice) {

            case 'c':
                System.out.println("Enter first name, last name and phone number");

                addressBook.addContact();

                count++;

                System.out.println("Total number of contact: " + count);

                break;

            case 'e':
                System.out.println("Enter name to be edited");

                first = input.next();
                last = input.next();
                num = null;

                person = new Contact(first, last, num);
                addressBook.edit(person);

                break;
            case 'd':
                System.out.println("Enter name to be deleted");

                first = input.next();
                last = input.next();
                num = null;

                person = new Contact(first, last, num);

                addressBook.removeContact(person);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Operation does not exist");
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize `char choice` to a default char:

`char choice = 'a';`

Then move all of this:

```
System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
System.out.println("Type c to create");
System.out.println("Tpe e to edit");
System.out.println("Tpe d to delete");
System.out.println("Type q to quit");

choice = input.next().charAt(0);
```

Inside your while loop:

```
while ('q' != choice) {
    //show menu options
    //allow user to select a menu option

    //use switch to operate based on user decision

    //once the operation is complete, as long as the user didn't select q, 
    //the menu options show once more and allow another selection
}
```

Comment: but then I get an error for the (q!= choice) because choice is declared later on in the code

Comment: @Sidney, you're absolutely correct. Check my edit! An easy fix is to just declare `choice` ahead of time, initialize it to a default value, and then allow it to be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `choice`.

1.Change `while ('q' != choice)` to `while (true)`

2.Move below code inside while

```
     System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
     System.out.println("Type c to create");
     System.out.println("Tpe e to edit");
     System.out.println("Tpe d to delete");
     System.out.println("Type q to quit");
```

3. Add one extra case

```
 case 'q':

   break;
```

Comment: Yup, this is a good way to do it. Definitely cleaner. I wasn't sure where OP was in their lesson plan, so I went with the most straight forward suggestion :)

Comment: Extra variable means extra memory :)